# Writing select functions for customized Pony

Tags: python, python-2.7, ponyorm

A lot of times, I wrote queries like the following:

```
pony.orm.select(u for u in User if u.available and u.friends > 0 and ...)
```

So, I would like to write my own version of `select`, an alternative of it. Something like to avoid me writing every time the first part of the predicate, `if u.available and u.friends > 0`.

My question is more general: how can I write a function like `select` that it accepts arguments like those that `select` method or `count` method can accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's define a `User` entity in the following way:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pony.orm import *

db = Database('sqlite', ':memory:')

class User(db.Entity):
    username = Required(str, unique=True)
    password = Required(str)
    friends = Set("User", reverse='friends')  # many-to-many symmetric relation
    online = Required(bool, default=False)    # if user is currently online
    last_visit = Optional(datetime)           # last visit time
    disabled = Required(bool, default=False)  # if user is disabled by administrator

sql_debug(True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

Now we can define some convenient functions to retrieve most frequently used types of users. The first function will return the users who are not disabled by the admin:

```
def active_users():
    return User.select(lambda user: not user.disabled)
```

In that function I use `select` method of `User` entity which accepts a lambda function, but the same function can be written using global `select` function which accepts a generator expression:

```
def active_users():
    return select(u for u in User if not user.disabled)
```

The result of `active_users` function is a query object. You can call [`filter`](http://doc.ponyorm.com/queries.html#Query.filter) method of the query object to produce more specific query. For example, I can use `active_users` function to select active users whose names start with the 'A' letter:

```
users = active_users().filter(lambda user: user.name.startswith('A')) \
                      .order_by(User.name)[:10]
```

Now I want to find users who visit the site in a few last days. I can define another function which uses the query returned from the previous function and augment it in the following way:

```
def recent_users(days=1):
    return active_users().filter(lambda u: u.last_visit > datetime.now() - timedelta(days))
```

In this example I pass the `days` argument to the function and use its value inside the filter.

You can define a set of such functions which will form data access layer of your application. Some more examples:

```
def users_with_at_least_n_friends(n=1):
    return active_users().filter(lambda u: count(u.friends) >= n)

def online_users():
    return User.select(lambda u: u.online)

def online_users_with_at_least_n_online_friends(n=1):
    return online_users().filter(lambda u: count(f for f in u.friends if f.online) >= n)

users = online_users_with_at_least_n_online_friends(n=10) \
            .order_by(User.name)[:10]
```

In the examples above I define global functions. Another option is to define these functions as a classmethods of the `User` entity:

```
class User(db.Entity):
    username = Required(str, unique=True)
    ...
    @classmethod
    def name_starts_with(cls, prefix):
        return cls.select(lambda user: not user.disabled
                                       and user.name.startswith(prefix))

...
users = User.name_starts_with('A').order_by(desc(User.last_visit))[:10]
```

If you might want to have a generic function which can be applied to different entity classes, then you need to pass the entity class as a parameter. For example, if a number of different classes have the `deleted` attribute, and you want to have a generic method to select only non-deleted objects, you can write something like that:

```
def select_active(cls):
    return cls.select(lambda obj: not obj.deleted)

select_active(Message).filter(lambda msg: msg.author == current_user)
```

All functions provided above have one drawback - they are not composable. You cannot get a query from one function and augment it with another function. If you want to have a function which can augment existing query, that function should accept the query as an argument. Example:

```
def active_users():
    return User.select(lambda user: not user.disabled)

def name_starts_with(query, prefix):
    return query.filter(lambda user: user.name.startswith('prefix'))
```

The `name_starts_with` function can be applied to another query:

```
users1 = name_starts_with(active_users(), 'A').order_by(User.last_visited)
users2 = name_starts_with(recent_users(), 'B').filter(lambda user: user.online)
```

Also we are working on the query extension API which will allow a programmer to write custom query methods. When we release this API it will be possible to just chain custom query methods together in the following way:

```
select(u for u in User).recent(days=3).name_starts_with('A')[:10]
```

Hope I answered your question. If this is the case, please accept the answer as a correct one.